# Running IPython on Ubuntu in VirtualBox

Tags: server, virtualbox, ipython

I have installed all the necessary packages to run IPython in Ubuntu under VirtualBox. Once I close the Ubuntu server, is it necessary to reinstall all the packages again to run IPython in VirtualBox the next time?

Answer (score 1):

The packages that you installed in the VirtualBox guest OS are installed permanently. You might also want to save a snapshot after you install packages so you can restore the guest OS back to the last known working snapshot in case something goes wrong later on. Snapshot 3 is highlighted in the screenshot which was saved after installing phpMyAdmin in Ubuntu 18.04.

[image: VirtualBox snapshots]